# Field name not found on selected data source - radio button list imageurl

Tags: c#, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I am getting the following error when I open a particular page of my site on the live web server.

"A field with the name 'imgURL' was not found on the selected data source."

I am using ASP with C# in VS2010. I don't get the error message when I am developing and viewing the page locally.

Both instances point to the same remote database and are executing the same stored procedure. I don't see why I get this message when the page is live on the web server

The function in my code behind calls a stored procedure to populate 5 radio button lists.
For one radio button list, I want to show images on the buttons, hence why I retrieve the "imgURl" field and try bind it to the control.  In debug on my local pc I can see, "ID", "DESC" and "imgURL" in the var "resultslist", so the stored procedure does seem to be returning the field OK!

I am obviously puzzled as to why it works locally but not on the main server?

Any help greatly appreciated

---

protected void BindBookDetailsToRBLBox()
    {

```
    ASPxRadioButtonList[] rblList = new ASPxRadioButtonList[5];
    rblList[0] = rblInteriors;
    rblList[1] = rblBind;
    rblList[2] = rblPaper;
    rblList[3] = rblLam;
    rblList[4] = rblTrim;

    // get the current radio button list box values.
    // this is called each time the page loads or the control posts a change to its index
    int[] bookDetailIDs = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    getSelectedRBLBoxValues(ref bookDetailIDs);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        int? returnCode = 0;
        if (bookDetailIDs[i] == 0)
        {
            try
            {
                var resultsList = db.getValidCombos(RequiredData[i], 
                                  bookDetailIDs[0], bookDetailIDs[1], 
                                  bookDetailIDs[2], bookDetailIDs[3], 
                                  bookDetailIDs[4], ref returnCode).ToList();


                // bind the data to the radio button list control
                rblList[i].DataSource = resultsList;
                rblList[i].ValueField = "ID";
                if (i == 4)
                    rblList[i].ImageUrlField = "imgURL";
                rblList[i].TextField = "DESC";

                rblList[i].DataBind();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                Log_Error.AddToErrorLog("printingbooks.ascx.cs", 
                                  "BindBookDetailsToRBLBox", string.Empty, ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the return type of `getValidCombos`? does that return type object has property called `imgURL`?

Comment: Hi, the return type of the method is automatically created by LINQ when it executes to SPROC (db.getValidCombos(...)). It returns a sequence of objects, each with a string, an int and a string (DESC, ID and imgURL). It is definitely returning values for imgURL - I can see them when in debug.

Comment: I worked out the problem. My automatically created LINQ data classes .cs source file was out of date on the live server. It didn't have the same return type as the version on my local machine! Thanks Damith for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

try with below

```
rblList[i].DataSource = resultsList.Select(x=> new{imgURL =x.imgURL, ID =x.ID}) ;
```

Comment: this runs fine locally too but when i load up on the live server and open the page, i get the following

"Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'getValidCombosResult' does not contain a definition for 'imgURL' and no extension method 'imgURL' accepting a first argument of type 'getValidCombosResult' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"